# Llamar a un metodo desde el plantilla Blade Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, blade

Bien, el nombre de la pregunta quizás suene estupida, y muy probablemente sea una mala practica pero es para que entiendan lo que quiero hacer.

Tengo un template `blade` que es general para todas las vistas de mi sitio web, o almenos para mas de un 80%. Ahora en este template tengo que cargar siempre los datos de usuario, ya saben, `nombre, apellido, fotografia, etc.`

Ahora, se que la forma correcta de hacerlo es que en cada methodo que devuelva una vista, hacer la consulta y devolver esto en un `compact`

```
return view('Paciente.create',['register'=>'true'],compact('user_data'));
```

Pero como dije, esto tendria que hacerlo en el 80% de las vistas y seria muy tedioso, incluso. Existe alguna otra de cargar este `compact` para todas las vistas en general, y asi no tener que hacerlo uno por uno?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar en cada una de las páginas `Auth::user()` seguido del campo `{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}` `{{ Auth::user()->last_name }}` `{{ Auth::user()->photo }}` sin necesidad de envíar la información desde el controlador.

Claro, el usuario debe estar logeado para esto.

Comment: Olvide agregar que tengo diferentes tipos de usuario. La tabla `users` guarda un `role`, y luego cada role tiene su `tabla independiente`. Para Pacientes hay una tabla que hereda el `user_id` que los relaciona. Entonces lo de first_name, last_name no funcionaria pues no estan en la tabla `users` que supongo que es de donde saca esos datos. Al final parece que terminare haciendo una funcion `userData` y enviare los datos por `compact`. Es lo mas practico y seguro en mi caso.

Comment: Igualmente se puede, debes relacionar las tablas en Laravel y funciona sin problemas... No recuerdo en este momento, pero podría funcionar igualmente como está `{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}` o `{{ Auth::user()->nombre_de_la_table->first_name }}` en tu ejemplo, si la tabla se llama pacientes ``{{ Auth::user()->pacientes->first_name }}``